# How to integrate windows on icinga2?

Tags: windows, configuration, monitoring, nagios, icinga

I'm new on Linux/monitoring and try my best :)
So I set up the latest Icinga2 with Icinga2 Web on Ubuntu.
All seems good to work. Now I'm trying to integrate a windows host.

These Steps I did:

1. edit the `icinga.conf` and added `include <windows-plugins>`
2. installed the Icinga client on Windows (7)
3. Generated a Setup Ticket for the client on Icinga
4. executed `sudo icinga2 node update-config` on icinga

My host appears on icinga but there are no thresholds for example at the CPU load. On `/usr/share/icinga2/include/command-plugins-windows.conf` are thresholds defined.

Why they do not working?

For each host icinga2 creates a new entry for host and service in the repository
`/etc/icinga2/repository.d/hosts/PC-01.Domain.local`

For each services there is an *.conf that looks like:

```
object Service "load" {
    import "satellite-service"
    check_command = "dummy"
    host_name = "PC-01.Domain.local"
    zone = "PC-01.Domain.local"
}
```

The check_command seems not to be the right one. It should be "loads-windows".
But why does it work?

Comment: The checks are executed on your client, but not the master where you'll just update the configuration with 'node update-config' putting a dummy check command. In order to use the clients with local configuration, modify the config with thresholds on your windows client itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue for windows server.

Following steps resolved issue -

- Modify "C:\Program Files (x86)\ICINGA2\share\icinga2\include\command-plugins-windows" file with appropriate threshold values as per your requirement.
- Restart Icinga2 service.

Comment: There are multiple options to monitor windows using icinga2, you may use NSClient, icinga agent which comes with pre-loaded remote checker or snmp. As of now most of the requirements are met with snmp, given the complexity and limited windows plugins in icinga.